# Map Google Drive to drive letter

Tags: windows, sync, google-drive

Google Drive has recently updated the desktop file sync client from the old Backup and Sync to a new system.  With the old program, I used `net use` at the Windows Command Prompt, e.g. `net use r: "\\localhost\c$\path\to\my\Google Drive"` to map my Google Drive folder to drive letter `R:\`, that way it'd be consistent on any machine.  But, with the new program, trying something similar, `net use m: "\\localhost\j$\My Drive"` yields this error:

```
System error 53 has occurred.

The network path was not found.
```

The path `J:\` used by the new Google Drive is actually a virtual drive, which may be the issue.  I also had issues with the `subst` command.  How do I map my `My Drive` folder to a persistent drive letter that will cooperate with Google's file syncing?  In case it matters, I'm on Windows 10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per [this post](https://support.google.com/drive/thread/133721471/map-google-drive-subfolder-to-a-drive-letter), it isn't possible because of the way the virtual drive works.